# Resource id #9 showing

Tags: php, sql

So i'm trying to get a list of activities(subjects) of a school and i get them all like it's on the Database but i also gives me Resource id #9 i've tried to remake the code so many times but it gives me every single time this.

**1st try**

```
<li>
            <?php
                if(Session[tipo]<=1){
                    echo "

                    <li class='treeview'>
                      <a href='#'>
                        <i class='fa fa-share'></i> <span>Atividades</span>
                        <i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
                      </a>
                      <ul class='treeview-menu'>
                        <li>".
                                $result = mysql_query("select * from atividade_aluno where ativo=1");                                                                       
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {                                     
                                echo "<a href='lista.php?x=$row->id_atividade'>". utf8_encode($row->atividade)."</a>";                                                                      
                                ?>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?><?php
                            echo "
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>";
                }else{                      
                    echo "<a href='#'>1</a>";
                }

            ?>
        </li>
```

**2nd try**

```
<li>
                <?php
                    if(Session[tipo]<=1){
                        echo "

                        <li class='treeview'>
                          <a href='#'>
                            <i class='fa fa-share'></i> <span>Atividades</span>
                            <i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
                          </a>
                          <ul class='treeview-menu'>
                            <li>".
                                    $result = mysql_query("select * from atividade_aluno where ativo=1");                                                                       
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {                                     
                                    echo "<a href='lista.php?x=".$row["id_atividade"]."'>". utf8_encode($row["atividade"])."</a>";                                                                      
                                    ?>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                ?><?php
                                echo "
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>";
                    }else{                      
                        echo "<a href='#'>1</a>";
                    }

                ?>
            </li>
```

**PS:** The result is the same so i won't upload two pictures of the same.

[image]

Thanks you so mutch for your time

Comment: `Session[tipo]`? That's not valid PHP. constants cannot be used as an array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: You code is complete garbage, it's very unreadable. But anyway it's because you cannot have statements in string concatenation. Or you can, but it'll "work" like you see.

Comment: Don't worry OP, my code was much worse than yours when I started :)

Comment: Well sorry guys, it's that i'm not very experienced in coding yet.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` operator concatenates strings in PHP. For example, this prints "helloworld":

```
$a = "hello";
$b = "world";
echo $a . $b;
```

Now, in your code you have this:

```
<li>".
```

This concatenates to the next variable (`$result`). You should change it to:

```
<li>";
```

Comment: I added some more explanation :)

Comment: this now makes alot more sence. Thanks you very mutch i didn't knew what concatenates was had to google it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this

```
<li>
            <?php
                if(Session[tipo]<=1){

                    $result = mysql_query("select * from atividade_aluno where ativo=1");

                    echo "

                    <li class='treeview'>
                      <a href='#'>
                        <i class='fa fa-share'></i> <span>Atividades</span>
                        <i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
                      </a>
                      <ul class='treeview-menu'>
                        <li>".                                                                                                      
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {                                     
                                echo "<a href='lista.php?x=$row->id_atividade'>". utf8_encode($row->atividade)."</a>";                                                                      
                                ?>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?><?php
                            echo "
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>";
                }else{                      
                    echo "<a href='#'>1</a>";
                }

            ?>
        </li>
```

You concatenated $result which is resource id with your string. That is the reason.

Comment: This code will try to concatenate with `while` instead of `$result`.